# Understanding some aspects of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are a couple of aspects of node.js I don't quite understand. I hope someone can make things clearer

When you install node.js where do you store your files so that the web browser can display your content? For example Apache have a www folder.

Does node.js replace client side javascript?

How does node.js interact with HTML? For example if I wanted to put data from the server into this div element `<div id="content"></div>`
In PHP you could do something like this: `<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>`

Would you ever call node.js from client side? For example: An Ajax request to node.js to get data.

Whats confusing me is that because it is run from the server then I expect that I can use javascript on the browser to get data from the node.js server. However, examples I seen this is never done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you install node.js where do you store your files so that the web browser can display your content? For example Apache have a www folder.

Wherever you want. node.js doesn't serve static content, it runs JavaScript. You tell it which script to run when you start it.

You could write some JavaScript that serves static content, but where you would keep it depends on the code you wrote.

> Does node.js replace client side javascript?

Only in so far as any server side programming replaces client side JavaScript.

One advantage of using JS on the server side is that you can reuse libraries on both the client and the server. See [Mojito](http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/) for a framework that claims to focus on this (I haven't had time to try it myself yet).

> For example if I wanted to put data from the server into this div element `<div id="content"></div>` In PHP you could do something like this: `<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>`

PHP is a template language with an embedded programming language. JavaScript is a programming language. Typically you would use a template language (e.g. [moustache](http://mustache.github.com/)) from your JS.

> Would you ever call node.js from client side? For example: An Ajax request to node.js to get data.

Yes, if you want to. Just like any other server side programming environment. (Assuming you are using node to run an HTTP server).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see examples that involved the server pushing data to the browser. Does that mean that js on the client needs to listen to requests from the server?

Comment: Getting data over HTTP works the same way as usual. It doesn't matter what language is running the server. (So maybe, it depends on what you mean by 'push').

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not a server (like e.g. Apache). It's a platform to run Javascript with some built in libraries (so-called modules). It is very easy to write server (HTTP or any other) in Node.js, but you can also write completely different programs (no network related, meant to be executed locally).

I suggest you read this: http://www.nodebeginner.org/. It took me several hours but allowed me to understand basics of Node without much pain.

As for client side scripting, it's generally separate. Code in Node runs in separate environment then the one in browser. They can communicate, but you have to explicitly make them to. It's not much different from server side coding in PHP. The code on server produces some output (eg. HTML) which is sent to client. If there are scripts in output, client (browser) executes it. They can communicate (via XHR, websockets, etc.), but by itself those scripts are separate.

Comment: @Quentin's answer is totally correct, but I think it may be a bit difficult to understand for someone who just starts to learn Node. I am one of those and several weeks ago I had similar questions to this. So I tried to put it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> How does node.js interact with HTML? For example if I wanted to put
>   data from the server into this div element  In
>   PHP you could do something like this:

You would probably send the content as JSON to the JS-Client and insert it into the DOM (using plain JS or JQuery).

I've wrote a *REALLY* trivial (and not quite feature-rich :-P) [chat application](https://github.com/helpermethod/real-time-web-applications) in Node.js a while a go, to try out some concepts and understand working with JS on both the client and server. Maybe it will give you some clues.

**EDIT**

In this application, the server also serves static files, which you should not do when implementing production ready application (Node is not really suited for serving static files!).