# node.js query and clarity of understanding

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding some aspects of node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449347/understanding-some-aspects-of-node-js)

How does node.js interact with HTML?

See this element and let me know as to how the PHO is working for something as under
hope am clear in making it simpler as possible.

Please help me understand the same in the context and the thing being talked about the same.

This is bugging me off not able to get the content material for the same

```
 <div id="content"></div> In PHP you could do something like this: <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

Comment: *hope am clear*, no. You're not at all. Furthermore profanity is not appreciated **anywhere** on the Stack Exchange Network, although TBH, neither are questions that show as little effort as this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449347/understanding-some-aspects-of-node-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449347/understanding-some-aspects-of-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a node.js web framework like http://expressjs.com/ if you're looking to build a website with it.